# es6 class bind vs class declaration

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, ecmascript-6, closures

Don't know if the title describes the best my question but here what I need to know:

I'm using **reactjs** with **es6** classes and I need to make a kind of mixin

I use a function **SuperMixin** as a wrapper for my class.

The first approach is to have a class in a *closure* so this will be created only once, and using `bind()` when calling **SuperMixin** to pass a parameter to that class.

```
let SuperMixin = (() => {
  class Mixin extends Component {
    constructor(InnerComponent){
      super();
      this.InnerComponent = InnerComponent;
    }
    render(){
      return <this.InnerComponent />
    }
  }
  return function(InnerComponent) {
    let newMixin = Mixin.bind(null, InnerComponent);
    newMixin.propTypes = {
      txt:propTypes.string.isRequired
    }
    return newMixin;
  }
})()

let ButtonMixed = SuperMixin(ButtonComponent)
```

The second approach is to create each time the class when **SuperMixin** wrapper is called:

```
let SuperMixin = InnerComponent => {
  class Mixin extends Component {
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.InnerComponent = InnerComponent;
    }
    render(){
      return <InnerComponent />
    }
  }

  Mixin.propTypes = {
      txt:propTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  return Mixin;
}

let ButtonMixed = SuperMixin(ButtonComponent)
```

Now, I know that `bind()` creates a new function, is this case a new class, so  when it comes to memory efficiency which approach is the best taking in cosideration the instances of class `Mixin`?

From what I think, both approaches will create the same number or instaces, is this correct or some other logic is involved using `bind()` method?

*PS: if you can help me with title refactoring, please ping me :)*

Comment: Use decorators instead of mixins https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750

Comment: does babeljs has support for decorators?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

Comment: The article you linked is anti-mixin, but the code in this question isn't actually a mixin. Not sure why it is using that name. Using decorators for this case is unnecessary. Your second example seems like the right approach to me.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes I know it's not actually a mixin, that's why I said "a kind of..." because I didn't knew how to call it...about that link and decorators, it wasn't my ideas. But what about memory efficiency?

Comment: Sorry I was referring to the article @elmeister posted. Use decorators if you want, but remember they are entirely experimental and you could have to refactor all of your code in the future. And I say this as the author of the Babel plugin he linked to :P BTW I'd just call what you're doing wrapping the component, rather than mixin or something.